# How to add item last and remove first item in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is like this:

```
data = {
  "a": [420, 380, 390],
  "b": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to add new item at the end of this dataframe, and remove the first item. I mean cont will be 3 each addition.

New item add

```
{"a": 300, b: 88}
```

and last stuation will be:

```
data = {
  "a": [380, 390, 300],
  "b": [40, 45, 88]
}
```

Is there a short way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) because `append` is getting deprecated. [Ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

```
dct = {"a": 300, "b": 88}
df_new = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(dct).to_frame().T]
                  ).iloc[1:, :].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)

# If maybe the values of 'dict' have multiple items.
# dct = {"a": [300, 400], "b": [88, 98]}
# df_new = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(dct)]
#                   ).iloc[1:, :].reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can add a new row to `df` with [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) then drop the first-row base number of `index`. (At the end use `reset_index` if it is necessary)

```
dct = {"a": 300, "b": 88}
df_new = df.append(dct, ignore_index=True).drop(0, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
     a   b
0  380  40
1  390  45
2  300  88
```

Comment: `append` is getting deprecated and will be removed from pandas

Answer (score 1):

Using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[1:],
                pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: d}, orient='index')], 
               ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     a   b
0  380  40
1  390  45
2  300  88
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append new row to existing dataframe by `df.append()`. In your example, this would be

```
new_row = {"a": 300, "b": 88}
df2 = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

(Notice that `append` works both for `Dataframe` and `dict` objects, but the later requires `ignore_index=True`.

And you can remove the first row from dataframe by one of the following methods:

1. Select using `iloc`

```
df3 = df2.iloc[1:, :]
```

This slices all rows but the first one, and all columns.

2. Use drop to remove the first row.

```
df3 = df2.drop(df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=False)
```

Or you could use `inplace=True` to modify `df2` inplace, `None` will be returned in that case.